# Mysql insert not working and not giving errors

Tags: php, mysql

i do not know why the following code will not work for inserting data into mysql.

```
if (!$link = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'password')) {
    echo '700';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('vendors', $link)) {
    echo '701';
    exit;
}
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO transactions (TransID, payment_status, last_name, first_name, payer_email, address_name, address_state, address_zip, address_country, verify_sign, payment_gross, ipn_track_id, business, reciver_email) VALUES ('kris', 'kris', 'kris', 'kris', 'kris','kris', 'kris', 'kris', 'kris', 'kris', 'kris', 'kris', 'kris', 'kris')";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $link);
```

What is wrong with the code? 
php is giving no errors.

Comment: I am unable to echo errors as this is part of a paypal ipn system im just storing the data paypal sends into a script before the ipn process it

Comment: you are passing `'kris'` in `TransID field`, is it `varchar or int`?

Comment: Use [error_reporting(E_ALL);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to see what error occurs?. Also check the column's datatype for each field.

Comment: use `mysqli` or `PDO`, `PHP` will remove `mysql` at the end of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try not to use **mysql_connect** instead use **mysqli_connect** or **PDO_MySQL** [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)

Also use **[die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#refsect1-function.mysql-connect-examples)** to find if there is any errors in your code

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Otherwise(recommended way)-

**Procedural style**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Persons (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('Happy', 'John', 'john@example.com')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New Person created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

**MySQLi Object-oriented style**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO Persons (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('Happy', 'John', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New Person created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
 $result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $link);
```

Into this

```
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $link)or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code like below to get the errors in your code

```
$result = mysql_query($sql2,$link) or die(mysql_error());
```

this `or die(mysql_error())` will give you errors in query