# MySQL INSERT INTO doesn't work but gives no error

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having trouble inserting a row into a MySQL table with Java. I'm not sure what the problem is as it isn't giving an error. I'm trying to insert the row with the following:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO users (uuid, authKey, code, scratches) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
PreparedStatement insertStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
insertStmt.setString(1, uuid);
insertStmt.setString(2, key);
insertStmt.setInt(3, code);
insertStmt.setString(4, getScratchString());

insertStmt.executeUpdate();
```

The table 'users' is created successfully with no errors with the following:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (uuid VARCHAR(40), authKey VARCHAR(30), code INT(10), scratches VARCHAR(45));");
```

When trying to insert the row with the same update in phpmyadmin, it works fine. There is no error given by the update so I have no idea where to start debugging. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to commit the transaction after insert?

Comment: please show an [MCVE]

Comment: @SumanthM That worked, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql insert not working and not giving errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734963/mysql-insert-not-working-and-not-giving-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do commit transaction check the below code

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO users (uuid, authKey, code, scratches) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement insertStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
insertStmt.setString(1, uuid);
insertStmt.setString(2, key);
insertStmt.setInt(3, code);
insertStmt.setString(4, getScratchString());
insertStmt.executeUpdate();      
connection.commit();
```

Comment: Where did that `preparedStmt.execute();` come from?

Comment: @Andreas : It's typo mistake. Edited

Comment: Why are you trying to insert the same record twice? Both `executeUpdate()` and `execute()` will run the `INSERT` statement, and with the same parameters, since they haven't been changed between the two calls. --- So I'll repeat my original question: Where did the `execute()` come from?